# Multiply trig functions of the same base?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Is $\frac{1}{\sin(x)}\frac{\cos(x)}{\sin(x)} = \frac{\cos(x)}{\sin^2(x)}$ correct?

Comment: Yes, it's correct.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the rule

$$\frac{a}{b} \cdot \frac{c}{d} = \frac{ac}{bd}$$ iff $b,d \not= 0$

always holds. With $a=1$, $b=d=\sin(x)$ and $c=\cos(x)$ we get the result:

$$\frac{\cos(x)}{\sin^2(x)}$$